# Setting textIsSelectable on TextView with marquee ellipsize adds ellipse

Tags: android, textview

A screen in my app will potentially post really long strings into a `TextView`.  For this scenario, I have `android:ellipsize="marquee"` set so the text will marquee across the TextView.

However, I've decided I also want this text to be selectable (`android:textIsSelectable="true"`).  In most cases, this is no problem.  The text is smaller than the TextView and the user can just select it.  However, if I have the `textIsSelectable` attribute and if the text is bigger than the TextView, the text will pick up an ellipse instead of being the full string.  **It will still marquee**, but it no longer displays the full text.  It cuts it off and displays an ellipse.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true">
```

Is there a way to have the text selectable and still maintain the entire string in the marquee (no ellipse)?

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: You want select text and also scroll text in textview/

Comment: Yes.  That is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be sure if this is a bug.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Note that we're setting `android:ellipsize="start"` in xml - more on this later.

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        mTextView.setSelected(true);
    }
});
```

`setEllipsize(TruncateAt)` checks whether the current `ellipsize` value is the same as the supplied one. To get around this, we supply `android:ellipsize="start"` in xml. This way, the `TextView` has no problem accepting `TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE` later on.

Now, even though this works, I will suggest you don't do this. You'll be able to see why - once you try this code. It seems `textIsSelectable` *is not supposed to be used with `marquee`* - the selection handles don't move along with the text.

All in all, it looks extremely sketchy.